# Where have you ever traveled to or where have you traveled to?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, sentence-meaning, present-perfect

Are all these questions grammatical?what's the difference in meaning between them?

1. Where have you ever traveled to?
2. Where have you traveled to?
3. Where have you already traveled to?

Asking about people's travels in general.

1. t's a very open question, meaning anytime in your life, so "ever" sounds possible.
2. Sounds ok
3. Already shows surprise because something happened too soon.

Comment: Don't use **ever** here.  It's an intensifier, and here it gives the implication that you think the person hasn't ever been anywhere, like "Have you *ever* been anywhere?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Ever" serves merely to add a little emphasis to the question. The meaning is exactly the same as 2 but it sounds unnatural.
2. "Already" is redundant. It serves no purpose except to make for a clumsy sentence. You would typically use "already" when asking a question about something being finished/accomplished ahead of the expected time. "Have you finished the job already?"

On the other hand, you might ask: "Have you been there already?" although this question is more likely in the context of a visit that day or very recently.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say all are good and valid.

The "ever" in #1 may be unnecessary, depending on context. #2, taken by itself, would mean "ever". Adding the word "ever" would emphasize this. It could be necessary if in context you were talking about a specific period of time.

Like suppose someone asked you, "Where did you travel last year?" You reply, "To France and Japan. Where have you traveled?" Now the question may be ambiguous. Do you mean last year, because we were just talking about last year? Or do you mean ever? Adding "ever" here would make it clear. (Or adding "last year" if that's what you meant.)

"Already" could be necessary if in context you were talking about future planned travel. Like, "Where are you planning to travel this year?" "Oh, I'm going to France. Where have you traveled?" The past tense indicates that you mean in the past and not future plans, but adding "already" would clarify or emphasize that you mean in the past.

I think "already" would be more likely in a statement. Like, "I want to visit all the countries in Europe. This year I am planning to visit France. I have already traveled to Germany and Belgium." Again, the past tense indicates that you mean trips already taken, but the "already" emphasizes and clarifies this.